# member template specialization and its scope

Tags: c++, templates, scope, specialization

It appears to me that C++ does not allow member template specialization in any scope other than namespace and global scope (MS VSC++ Error C3412). But to me it makes sense to specialize a base class's primary member template in the derived class because that is what derived classes do - specialize things in the base class. For instance, consider the following example:

```
struct Base
{
  template <class T>
  struct Kind
  {
      typedef T type;
  };
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  /* Not Allowed */
  using Base::Kind;
  template <>
  struct Kind <float> 
  {
    typedef double type;
  };
};

int main(void)
{
  Base::Kind<float>::type f;    // float type desired
  Derived::Kind<float>::type i; // double type desired but does not work.
}
```

My question is why isn't it allowed?

Comment: BTW, there is a confirmed bug #39906 (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39906) in g++ that incorrectly accepts similar code. However, Comeau and VC++ do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do, but you are not doing it right. Try this :

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived{};

// Original definition of Kind
// Will yield an error if Kind is not used properly
template<typename WhatToDo, typename T>
struct Kind
{
};

// definition of Kind for Base selector
template<typename T>
struct Kind<Base, T>
{
  typedef T type;
};

// Here is the inheritance you wanted
template<typename T>
struct Kind<Derived, T> : Kind<Base, T>
{
};

// ... and the specialization for float
template<>
struct Kind<Derived, float>
{
  typedef double type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why isn't it allowed?

From my copy of the draft it appears that the following puts the above restriction:

> In
>   an explicit specialization declaration for a class template, a member of a class template or a class member
>   template, the name of the class that is explicitly specialized shall be a simple-template-id.

The workaround is to specialize the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

I will "ignore" the standard specifications and try a logical argument:

If you have two classes:

```
class A
{
   struct S { };

};

class B: public A
{
   struct S { };
};
```

A::S and B::S are two different types. Extending the logic to the template specializations, when you try to specialize an inner class declared in base class through an inner class in derived class, you actually are trying to define a different type, with the same name (but another naming scope).